# What is a good free software to draw complicated Venn diagrams?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-software

The important feature I want is this : I would like to draw two sets as say ovals in solid line but I would like to have the border line in some neighborhood of their two intersection points to be dashed. This I want so as to indicate that I am not sure if these two sets intersect or not.

What is a simple and hopefully available online software to do this?

Comment: If your aim to help visualize relationships between more than 3 sets, Venn diagrams are not very useful. See examples at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: Have you tried googling on "venn diagram software" (without the quote marks)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try eulerAPE.  It is available online via this [link](http://www.eulerdiagrams.org/eulerAPE/).

Answer (score 1):

Geogebra would best suit your purpose.